# Change the required attribute from false to true

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework

```
$this->addElement('text', 'firstname', array(
    'required' => false,
    'label' =>Name,
     'value'=>$this->data['firstname'],
    'class' => 'span4'
));
```

I want that required attribute to be changed from false to true,Using jquery.  Is it possible??

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

**In Jquery 1.6 and above**

```
$(".span4").prop("required", false);
```

**In Jquery 1.5 and below**

```
$(".span4").attr("required", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you would do:

```
$(".span4").attr("required", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'required' property is the internal property of Zend_Form_Element and it isn't rendered in HTML. Then you can't change it on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in your question is a server-side validation provided by Zend Framework.
It's only validate your field when you press submit button.

If you dont want it simply remove it.